# Why is the Azure DevOps Build Pipeline fails to download the source code with an error?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, tfvc

I am using Azure DevOps Server 2020 and the TFVC repo.
I have a build pipeline and it is currently failing at the Get Sources task while downloading the code. It download half and fails with the error "_Proc should be null. (Parameter '_proc)" (screenshot below for reference)

Can anyone help me on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted agent?  What version?  Did you update recently?  Are you on the latest version.  There was a developer community issue that matches this in the past which was a product issue.  You might try submitting a ticket there if you are on the latest everything.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/problem-running-azure-devops-build-linux-agent-aga/1117405

Comment: @Matt, yes it is a self-hosted agent and the agent version is 2.170.1.  I tried changing the agent in the pipeline and that agent gave me space related error saying low space on disk and when i checked C drive it had 6 GB free space so i went ahead and deleted some files and reran the build with the agent it was failing and this time it ran successfully weird and strange but true and now I created a new build for other solution  and it is also giving same error even though now I have 15 GB of free space.  I will also raise a ticket now.